# Unity: Singleton script needs to be re-attached to gameobject on Editor relaunch to avoid null error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton, nullreferenceexception

I'm having a problem with my singleton class scripts I'd like to get your help with.

The script ultimately works, but every time I launch the Unity Editor I need to remove and re-attach the scripts to my gameobject to avoid null exception errors:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Any ideas why? I'm thinking I'm not initialising properly, but don't know where to go from there.

Here's a simplified singleton code attached as a component:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Conductor : MonoBehaviour
 {
 
     public static Conductor Timing { get; private set; }
 
     [SerializeField] private double bpm;          // beats per minute
 
     private void Awake()
     {
         if (Timing != null && Timing != this)
             Destroy(this);
         else
             Timing = this;
     }
 
     public double Bpm
     {
         get { return bpm; }
         set
         {
             bpm = value;
         }
     }
 }
```

and I call the code in another script as follows e.g.

`Conductor.Timing.Bpm;`

Thanks in advance!

best, Rob

Comment: That other script.. is it an editor script? Otherwise if this is at runtime I don't see why it shouldn't work .. except maybe order of execution issues if the other scripts `Awake` is executed before this scripts ...

Comment: Hi, the reason was to do with instances not being launched in the Editor. I'm not sure I understand the solution well enough to explain it again, but the below did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer 1 minute after posting the question lol:

[ExecuteAlways]

at the top of the class seemed to fix it. I also put the script in question before the default execution time in script execution order